# Problems in Creating Energy Index-like Strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am having an issue with my code on Pinescript thus far. Specifically I have an issue right now that says,

> Error at 63:1 Mismatched input 'strategy' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

Before, I had issues with the array function. This is the code I'm working with:

```
//@version=5
//@Julian Jankowski
strategy("Energy Index vs. Crude Oil", overlay=true)

// Input for WTI crude oil
var wtiCrudeOilSymbol = input("BCOUSD", title="WTI Crude Oil Symbol")

// List of the top 10 energy companies by market cap, excluding Chinese companies
var energyCompanies = array.new_float(10)

array.set(energyCompanies, 0, request.security("2222.SR", "1D", close))
array.set(energyCompanies, 1, request.security("XOM", "1D", close))
array.set(energyCompanies, 2, request.security("CVX", "1D", close))
array.set(energyCompanies, 3, request.security("SHEL", "1D", close))
array.set(energyCompanies, 4, request.security("TTE", "1D", close))
array.set(energyCompanies, 5, request.security("COP", "1D", close))
array.set(energyCompanies, 6, request.security("NEE", "1D", close))
array.set(energyCompanies, 7, request.security("BP", "1D", close))
array.set(energyCompanies, 8, request.security("PBR", "1D", close))
array.set(energyCompanies, 9, request.security("TAQA.AE", "1D", close))

//Assign market cap values by company

MarketCap2222SR = 2158000000000
MarketCapXOM = 418920000000
MarketCapCVX = 273530000000
MarketCapSHEL = 216980000000
MarketCapTTE = 162980000000
MarketCapCOP = 137130000000
MarketCapNEE = 118070000000
MarketCapBP = 101240000000
MarketCapPBR = 99550000000
MarketCapTAQAAE = 99500000000

totalMarketCap = MarketCap2222SR + MarketCapXOM + MarketCapCVX + MarketCapSHEL + MarketCapTTE + MarketCapCOP + MarketCapNEE + MarketCapBP + MarketCapPBR + MarketCapTAQAAE

// Account for market cap as weighted
var weightedIndex = 0.0

for i = 0 to 9
    weightedIndex := weightedIndex + array.get(energyCompanies, i)

weightedIndex := weightedIndex / totalMarketCap

// Fetch WTI crude oil data
var wtiCrudeOilClose = request.security(wtiCrudeOilSymbol, "1D", close)

// Compare the weighted index to crude oil prices
var buyCondition = weightedIndex > wtiCrudeOilClose
var sellCondition = weightedIndex < wtiCrudeOilClose

// Calculate stop-loss and take-profit levels based on ATR (Average True Range)
var atrLength = input(14, title="ATR Length")
var stopLossFactor = input(1.5, title="Stop Loss ATR Multiplier")
var takeProfitFactor = input(2.0, title="Take Profit ATR Multiplier")

var atr = ta.atr(atrLength)
var stopLossPrice = close - (atr * stopLossFactor)
var takeProfitPrice = close + (atr * takeProfitFactor)

// Strategy orders
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, if buyCondition
strategy.exit("Take Profit/Stop Loss", from_entry="Buy", if sellCondition or close <= stopLossPrice or close >= takeProfitPrice, profit=150, loss=50)

// Plot weighted index and crude oil price
plot(weightedIndex, color=color.blue, title="Weighted Index")
plot(wtiCrudeOilClose, color=color.orange, title="WTI Crude Oil")

// Plot buy and sell signals on the chart
plotshape(buyCondition, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
plotshape(sellCondition, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small)
```

Please let me know what solutions I could implement both to resolve this issue and avoid other error messages.

Initially, I had an array problem, where I used "[]" instead of "()". I resolved this issue making this replacement. But this strategy has been such that when I solve one problem, another seems to emerge. Please let me know how to resolve permanently.

UPDATE: I have resolved the initial error. My problem now comes in the form of being unable to execute any trades. I know where the problem for that is though. In the market cap section, I have put a fixed number to the weighted value. The problem is that it lacks dynamism. I would ideally want to use an external source to show both who the top 10 companies (excluding Chinese companies) are and companies' respective market caps. How would I modify the array and market cap sections of the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates an indentation problem in line 63, where the local "if" code block is declared inside the strategy.entry() function instead of the qty= parameter.

```
// Strategy orders
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, if buyCondition
strategy.exit("Take Profit/Stop Loss", from_entry="Buy", if sellCondition or close <= stopLossPrice or close >= takeProfitPrice, profit=150, loss=50)
```

Move the `if` blocks to the global scope and follow the `strategy.entry/exit` function signature:

```
// Strategy orders
if buyCondition
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
if sellCondition or close <= stopLossPrice or close >= takeProfitPrice
    strategy.exit("Take Profit/Stop Loss", from_entry="Buy", profit=150, loss=50)
```